# Snake Game and Using Stacks

Tags: assembly, x86, nested, stack, procedure

I created a game of snake at class. We learned yesterday how to use the Stack Segment (push&pop) and black boxing
I tried to use it on my snake but it became lengthier and stopped working. Can someone help me identify the problem? Teach said that any proc. should start with push and end with pop but when I call other Proc. inside should it be the same or I should pop before I call the next Proc.? and how do I make sure which part is wrong? DOSBOX says 0 warning and 0 errors but when I play the snake don't move and the random object don't appear.

code added below:

```
         MODEL small
         STACK 100h
         DATASEG
snake_length dw 3
object dw ?
Clock equ es:6Ch
message db 'game over, do you want to play again$'
; --------------------------
CODESEG
proc cleanscreen
    push cx
    push bx
    push ax
    xor ax,ax
    mov cx,4000d
    mov bx,0
    clean:
    mov [es:bx],al
    inc bx
    loop clean
    pop ax
    pop bx
    pop cx
    ret
    endp cleanscreen
    
proc playgame ;starts the game
push ax
mov ax,0b800h
mov es,ax
pop ax
call cleanscreen
push bx
push dx
mov dh, 200
mov dl, '*'
xor bx,bx
mov di,2000d
mov [es:di],dx
mov [es:di-2],dx
mov [es:di-4],dx
mov [word ptr bx], 1996d
mov [word ptr bx+1], 1998d
mov [word ptr bx+2], di
pop dx
pop bx
call random
call movement
ret
endp playgame

proc movement
mov ah,1
int 16h
jnz skip
mov ah,0
int 16h
skip:
cmp al, 'w'
je wp
cmp al, 'a'
je ap
cmp al, 'd'
je dpointer
cmp al, 's'
je  spo
cmp al, 'q'
je endgame
call movement

wp:
sub di,160d
jmp update
spo:
add di,  160d
jmp update
dpointer:
add di,2d
jmp update
ap:
sub di,2d
update:
call bounderies
ret
endp movement

proc bounderies
push ax
push dx
push bx
cmp di,160d 
jb endgame
cmp di, 38940
ja endgame
mov ax,di
mov bl, 160d
div bl
cmp ah,0
je endgame
inc ax
mov ax,di
div bl
cmp ah,0
je endgame
pop bx 
pop dx
pop ax
call update_snake
ret
endp bounderies

proc update_snake
push bx
push si
push cx
mov cx, offset snake_length
xor bx,bx
xor ch,ch
mov si,[bx]
mov [es:si], ch
transition:
mov si,[bx+1]
mov [bx],si
loop transition
mov [bx], di
pop cx
pop si
pop bx
call delay
ret
endp update_snake

proc delay
push cx
push bx
    mov cx, 0FFFFh  
    lopa:
        mov bx, 50
        lopb:
            dec bx
            cmp bx, 0
            jnz lopb
    loop lopa
    ret
    pop bx
    pop cx
    call check_if_eaten
endp delay

proc endgame
ret
endp endgame

proc check_if_eaten
cmp di, [object]
jne restfunc
call random
restfunc:
call movement
ret
endp check_if_eaten

proc random
push ax
push bx
mov ax, [Clock] ; read timer counter
mov ah, [byte cs:bx] ; read one byte from memory
xor al, ah ; xor memory and counter
and al, 00001111b ; leave result between 0-15
sal al,1
mov [byte ptr object], al
pop bx
pop ax
ret 
endp random

start:
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax
    call playgame
exit:
    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h
END start
```

Comment: Push basically pushes the current state (contents of some registers probably) to the top of the stack. Pop restores the states by popping the top of the stack. If you want to call one procedure P2 from within another P1, then no need to call pop before calling P2, but rather you may just call push at the begging of procedure and pop at the end of procedure. In between push and pop, can be the body which can have calls to other procedures as well.

Comment: One issue I see is that in ‘delay’ you have ‘ret’ before the pops - that will cause a stack imbalance.

Comment: So many things wrong with this program. It's gonna take hours to review this! Please answer this question: Before you applied *"the `push` at the top and `pop` at the bottom"* thingy, was the program working or not?

Comment: One give-away: `Clock equ es:6Ch` The BIOS clock counter resides at linear address 046Ch, so this equate is only going to be useful if the `ES` segment register was pre-loaded with 0040h before trying to read the clock with an instruction like `mov ax, [Clock]`. Verify if this is the case in your code... Spoiler alert: it isn't!

Comment: @kiner_shah I totally understand what you are saying in your comment, but I fear the poor choice of words will confuse the OP even further. "... no need to **call pop** before calling P2, but rather you may just **call push** ..." If you would have written "... no need to *use* `pop` before calling P2, but rather you may just *use* `push` ...", the confusion would be less.

Comment: @SepRoland, yeah maybe you are right.

Comment: @SepRoland it actually worked before, the teacher just told us to put it without explaining and than it stopped working. We don't learn so well why we do things.
and about the clock, we have not learned yet how the clock works (the teacher just said to copy the random proc from our book) , how to fix this? I really want to understand why&how to do things.

Comment: Related: [The quintessential Snake Game. How to keep track of the snake?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66825708) - Sep Roland wrote up a full working version (not specifically using the stack more than normal.)