# Why a proc runs twice instead of an (almost) infinite loop?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16

this code is for snake game. the proc detect _ direction calls mov_snake proc that does
many things and ends up with calling detect_direction . when I run the code in DosBox (the most updated version) the snake location is being updated twice and the the code stoprun (not via the endgame proc, the line c:tasm/bin/ shows up again)

If you have any idea please comment it.

```
ideal
model small
stack 100h
dataseg
 message db 'game over, to play again press y$'
object_location dw 2
clock equ es:6ch
longer db 0
snake dw 2000 dup (0)
codeseg
proc cleanscreen ; cleans the screen
    push cx
    push bx
    mov cx,4000d
    mov bx,0
    clean:  mov [byte  ptr es:bx],0
    inc bx
    loop clean
    pop bx
    pop cx
    ret
endp cleanscreen

proc startgame
mov ax, 0b800h
mov es, ax 
call cleanscreen
mov dl, '*'
mov dh,200
mov di,2000d;snake head first position
mov [es:di], dx
mov [es:di-2], dx
mov [es:di-4], dx
mov [word ptr snake],1996d
mov [word ptr snake+2], 1998d
mov [word ptr snake+4], 2000d
mov cx, 3
call random
mov ah,0
int 16h
call detect_direction
ret
endp startgame

proc delay
push cx
push bx
    mov cx, 0ffffh ;delay loop
    lopa:
        mov bx, 20d
        lopb:
            dec bx
            cmp bx, 0
            jnz lopb
    loop lopa
    pop bx
    pop cx
    ret
endp delay

proc buffer
mov ah,1
int 16h
jz nothingchanged
mov ah,0
int 16h
nothingchanged:
ret
endp buffer

proc detect_direction
    cmp al, 'w'
    je up
    cmp al, 'a'
    je left
    cmp al, 'd'
    je right
    cmp al, 's'
    je  down
    cmp al, 'q'
    je gameover
up: sub di,160
jmp move_on
down: add di,160d
jmp move_on
right: add di,2
jmp move_on
left: sub di,2
jmp move_on
gameover:call endgame
move_on:
call move_func
ret
endp detect_direction

proc updatesnake
    push bx
    push si
    mov bx, offset snake 
    cmp [longer],1 ;if longer is one , increase snake length
    je increa
    mov si, [bx]
    mov [word ptr es:si], 0 ; delete tail
    sub bx,2
    increa:
        mov [es:di], dx
        add bx,2 ; prevent tail value from being deleted when being increased
    updateloop:
        mov si, [bx+2]
        mov [bx], si
        inc bx 
    loop updateloop
    mov [bx], di
    cmp [longer],1
    jne reg
    inc cx ; this prevent inseting a junk value when increasing snake's length
    reg:
    pop si
    pop bx
ret 
endp updatesnake

proc move_func
call updatesnake
call delay
call boundries
call check_if_eaten
call buffer
call detect_direction
ret
endp move_func

proc boundries
push ax
push dx
cmp di,160d
ja keep_playing
cmp di,3840d
jb keep_playing
mov ax,di
mov dl,160d
div dl
cmp ah,0
jne keep_playing
mov ax,di
inc ax
div dl
cmp ah,0
jne keep_playing
call endgame
keep_playing:
pop dx
pop ax
ret
endp boundries

proc random
push ax
push bx
push cx
push si
push dx
mov ax, [clock] ; read timer counter
mov cx, [word cs:bx] ; read one byte from memory
xor si, cx ; xor memory and counter
and si, 2000d ; leaves value between 0-2000
sal si,1 ; mult value
mov [object_location], si ; save in memory for future checking
mov dl,'@'
mov dh, 150
mov [es:si],dx
pop dx
pop si
pop cx
pop bx
pop ax
ret
endp random

proc check_if_eaten
mov [longer],0
cmp di, [object_location]
jne skip_increase
call random
mov [longer], 1
skip_increase:
ret
endp check_if_eaten

proc endgame
push dx
call cleanscreen
mov dx, offset message
mov ah,9h
int 21h
mov ah,0
int 16
cmp al, 'y'
jne line
call startgame
line:
pop dx
ret
endp endgame
start:
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax
    call startgame
exit:
    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h
end start
```

Comment: Have you tried single-stepping your code in a debugger?   There's a lot of code here, not easy to follow in my head.  So what do you see with a debugger?  What's different the 2nd iteration.

Comment: That `random` proc looks highly suspicious. It uses a couple of registers (`bx`, `si`) to access memory but I don't see them being initialized anywhere.

Comment: In `updatesnake` you have `loop updateloop`. This decrements `cx` - the snake length. Fine, but it does not appear to be restored again for the next iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has much improved since [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69862255/snake-game-and-using-stacks), but because of the many errors that are still in there, I doubt it if someone could fully answer your "WHY???"

I will focus on one of your procedures, *boundries*, where you want to end the game if the snake collides with the top- or bottom rows or left- or right columns

The first test, `cmp di,160` `ja keep_playing`, means that you keep playing provided the snake does not touch the top row of the screen. None of the other borders is even verified!
What you need if inverting the conditional jump like in `cmp di, 160` `jb stop_playing`.

In the fourth test (for the right side border) you divide an odd number (because of the `inc ax`) by 160. This will always yield a non-zero remainder. So, not a useful test. To test for left- and right borders, you can do with just one division and interpret the remainder twice: 0 is a left side collision and 158 is a right side collision.

```
proc boundries
  push ax
  push dx
  cmp  di, 160         ; Top row
  jb   stop_playing
  cmp  di, 3840        ; Bottom row
  ja   stop_playing
  mov  ax, di
  mov  dl, 160
  div  dl
  cmp  ah, 0           ; Left column
  je   stop_playing
  cmp  ah, 158         ; Right column
  jne  keep_playing    ; All 4 tests passed!
stop_playing:
  call endgame
keep_playing:
  pop  dx
  pop  ax
  ret
endp boundries
```

As a bonus the *random* procedure, where you read the *clock* in the `AX` register, but then suddenly you don't use `AX` and start using `SI` instead!

- The `mov ax, [clock] ; read timer counter` instruction will read the true clock as defined by your `clock equ es:6ch` equate if you temporarily set the `ES` segment register to the BIOS data page at 0040h:

  ```
    push es
    mov  ax, 0040h
    mov  es, ax
    mov  ax, [clock]    ; read timer counter
    pop  es
  ```
- An `AND` instruction like `and si, 2000 ; leaves value between 0-2000` will not limit the value the way you expect! Restricting to that particular range requires dividing by 2001 and using the remainder.

This is my version of the new *random* procedure:

```
proc random
  push ax          ; \
  push bx          ;  | (i)
  push dx          ; /

  push ds          ; (ii)
  xor  dx, dx      ; The word-sized `DIV` division requires this
  mov  ds, dx
  mov  ax, [046Ch] ; (iii) read timer counter
  pop  ds
  xor  ax, [cs:bx] ; XOR counter and a (randomly chosen?) WORD from memory
  mov  bx, 2000    ; (iiii)
  div  bx          ; DX:AX / BX -> Remainder in DX is [0,1999]
  shl  dx, 1       ; Convert into text video offset
  mov  bx, dx      ; Move to an address register
  mov  [object_location], bx
  mov  word [es:bx], 9640h ; Character @ with attribute 96h (150)

  pop  dx
  pop  bx
  pop  ax
  ret
endp random
```

(i) Less registers used == Less registers that need preserving!
(ii) Using `DS` gives shorter code.
(iii) Stop using the 'confusing' *clock* equ that has a `es:` segment override in it.
(iiii) To stay on the screen, the *object_location* should be restricted to {0, 2, 4, 6, ... , 3998].

---

I recently posted a Q/A [The quintessential Snake Game. How to keep track of the snake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66825708/the-quintessential-snake-game-how-to-keep-track-of-the-snake). Maybe that you could get one or two ideas from it...

Comment: Thank you! it's really helpful! I see the problem with using the si as it was written in the book. the div should be instead of the and right? not an addition to that line

Comment: @user17341742 See how the division is done in today's edit to the answer.

Comment: I noticed something strange in the random proc. it creates random '@' correctly but the '@' changes it's place any time I press on the keyboard. the only reason that I could see to that is if object location alway equals to di