# how to turn the snake (in snake game) in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I am taking an assembly course and I have to make a snake game as my project. I am using text mode and am working with characters instead of pixels. I am having trouble figuring out how to make the snake turn in different directions.

All I was able to do was to turn it 90 degrees which has no use. I would like to know if how to properly do the turning. BTW I am using 16 bit assembly x86 intel. For now I have hardcoded everything and am not using keyboard input.

```
[org 0x0100]
jmp _start

string : db 'Score '
len: dw 6

Snake_X : dw 10
Snake_Y : dw 5

X_speed: dw 1
Y_speed: dw 1

snakeLen: dw 6
_start:
    call cls
    call playingField
    push 0x000A
    call Score
    mov cx,2
    gameLoop:
        push word[snakeLen]        ; length of snake
        call PrintsnakeX           ; horizontal movement
        inc cx
    cmp cx,20
    jl gameLoop
    push 0x000A
    call sleep
    call cls
    call playingField
    push 0x000A
    call Score
    mov cx,2
    gameLoop1:
        mov ax,[snakeLen]
        push ax
        call PrintsnakeY    ; vertical movement
        inc cx
    cmp cx,10
    jl gameLoop1
end:
mov ax,0x4c00
int 0x21

PrintsnakeX: 
    push bp
    mov bp, sp
    push es
    push ax
    push cx
    push si
    push di
        mov ax, 0xb800
        mov es, ax              ; point es to video base
        mov cx, word[bp+4]          ; load length of snake in cx
        mov ax, 80              ; load ax with columns per row
        mul word[Snake_Y]        ;  y position
        add ax, word[Snake_X]         ;  x position
        shl ax, 1               ; turn into byte offset
        add ax,cx
        mov di,ax               ; point di to required location
        mov al, '*'          ; point si to string
        mov ah, 40h          ; load attribute in ah
        push di
        cld                     ; auto increment mode
        s1:
            cmp cx,0
            jz break1
            stosw
        dec cx
        jmp s1
        break1:
        push 0x000F
        call sleep
        mov ah,0x00
        pop di
        stosw
    mov ax,word[X_speed]
    add word[Snake_X],ax
    pop di
    pop si
    pop cx
    pop ax
    pop es
    pop bp
ret 2
PrintsnakeY: 
    push bp
    mov bp, sp
    push es
    push ax
    push cx
    push si
    push di
        mov ax, 0xb800
        mov es, ax              ; point es to video base
        mov cx, [bp+4]          ; load length of string in cx
        mov ax, 80              ; load al with columns per row
        mul word[Snake_Y]        ; multiply with y position
        add ax, word[Snake_X]         ; add x position
        add ax,cx
        add ax,3
        shl ax, 1               ; turn into byte offset
        mov di,ax               ; point di to required location
        mov al, '*'          ; point si to string
        mov ah, 40h          ; load attribute in ah
        push di
        cld                     ; auto increment mode
        .s1:
            cmp cx,0
            jz break
            stosw
            add di,158
        dec cx
        jmp .s1
        break:
        push 0x000F
        call sleep
        mov ah,0x00
        pop di
        stosw
     mov ax,word[Y_speed]
    add word[Snake_Y],ax
    pop di
    pop si
    pop cx
    pop ax
    pop es
    pop bp
ret 2
cls: 
    push es
    push ax
    push cx
    push di
    mov ax, 0xb800
    mov es, ax          ; point es to video base
    xor di, di          ; point di to top left column
    mov ax, 0x0720      ; space char in normal attribute
    mov cx, 2000        ; number of screen locations
    cld                 ; auto increment mode
    rep stosw           ; clear the whole screen
    pop di
    pop cx
    pop ax
    pop es
ret


sleep:
    push bp
    mov bp,sp
    push cx
    mov cx,[bp+4]
    d1:
        push cx
        mov cx,0xFFFF
        delayLoop1:
        loop delayLoop1
        pop cx
    loop d1
    pop cx
    pop bp
ret 2 

Score:
    push bp
    mov bp,sp
    push ax
    mov ax,24   ; y position of score string
    push ax
    mov ax,2    ; x position of score string 
    push ax
    mov ax, string   ; point to score string
    push ax 
    push word[len]   ; len of score string 
    call printstr
    mov ax,24
    push ax
    mov ax,8
    push ax
    mov ax,[bp+4]
    push ax
    call digits
    pop ax
    pop bp
ret 2

playingField:
    push es
    push ax
    mov ax ,0xb800
    mov es,ax
    mov ax,164
    push ax
    mov ax,74
    push ax
    call HLine
    mov ax,164
    push ax
    mov ax,21
    push ax
    call vLine
    mov ax,312
    push ax
    mov ax,21
    push ax
    call vLine
    mov ax,3524
    push ax
    mov ax,75
    push ax
    call HLine
    pop ax
    pop es
ret

HLine:
    push bp
    mov bp,sp           
    mov di,[bp+6]
    mov ax,0x4020
    mov cx,[bp+4]
    cld
    .lp2:
        stosw
    loop .lp2
    pop bp
ret 4
vLine:
    push bp
    mov bp,sp      
    mov di,[bp+6]
    mov ax,0x4020
    mov cx,[bp+4]
    cld
    .lp1:
        stosw
        add di,158
    loop .lp1
    pop bp
ret 4

printstr: 
    push bp
    mov bp, sp
    push es
    push ax
    push cx
    push si
    push di
        mov ax, 0xb800
        mov es, ax              ; point es to video base
        mov al, 80              ; load al with columns per row
        mul byte [bp+10]        ; multiply with y position
        add ax, [bp+8]         ; add x position
        shl ax, 1               ; turn into byte offset
        mov di,ax               ; point di to required location
        mov si, [bp+6]          ; point si to string
        mov cx, [bp+4]          ; load length of string in cx
        mov ah, 09h             ; load attribute in ah
        cld                     ; auto increment mode
        nextchar: 
        lodsb                   ; load next char in al
        stosw                   ; print char/attribute pair
    loop nextchar               ; repeat for the whole string
    pop di
    pop si
    pop cx
    pop ax
    pop es
    pop bp
ret 8

digits:
    push bp
    mov bp,sp
    push cx
    push ax
    push bx
    push dx
    push di
    mov ax, 0xb800
    mov es, ax  
    mov al, 80              ; load al with columns per row
    mul byte [bp+8]        ; multiply with y position
    add ax, [bp+6]         ; add x position
    shl ax, 1               ; turn into byte offset
    mov di,ax     
    mov ax,[bp+4]
    mov cx,0
    mov bx,10 
        lp1:
            mov dx,0
            div bx
            add dl,0x30
            push dx
            inc cx
            cmp ax,0
        jne lp1
        cld
        lp2:
            pop ax
            mov ah,0x07
            stosw
    loop lp2
    pop di
    pop dx
    pop bx
    pop ax
    pop si
    pop bp
ret 6
```

Comment: Turning the snake just means changing the motion you make at each step.  North is (0,-1), west is  (-1, 0), south is (0,1), east is (1,0).  So, turning 90 degrees clockwise means DX=-DY, DY=DX.  Turning 90 degrees counterclockwise means DX=DY, DY=-DX.

Comment: See [The quintessential Snake Game. How to keep track of the snake?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66825708) for a full working game, including keeping track of the current direction in a member of a struct global variable, `S.Flow`