# Checking for collision of snake with border in 8088 assembly language

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16, dos

```
org 0x100
jmp start
checkBorder:
    push bp
    mov bp,sp
    push ax
    push bx
    push cx
    push dx
    
    mov ax,[bp+6]
    mov bx,[bp+4]
    cmp ax,17
    jz over
    cmp ax,54
    jz over
    cmp bx,2
    jz over
    cmp bx,23
    jz over
    jmp nover
    over:
        mov ax,0xb800
        mov es,ax
        mov di,1974
        mov si,gover
        mov cx,[glen]
        mov ah,0x70
        cld
            next:
                lodsb
                stosw
                loop next
    mov  ah, 0              ; service 0 – get keystroke 
    int  0x16               ; call BIOS keyboard service 
    nover:
        pop dx
        pop cx
        pop bx
        pop ax
        pop bp
        ret 4
start:
    call clrscr
    mov bx,20
    mov dx,10
    mov [direction],0
    mov word[snake_location],
    l3:
        mov ax,0
        push ax
        call printScore
        mov ax,3
        push ax
        call printLives
        call printRec
        mov  ax, bx
        push ax                ; push x position
        mov  ax, dx
        push ax                ; push y position
        push word [length]     ; push message length
        push word[direction]
        call printSnake        ; call the printstr subroutine
        call delay
        call delay
        call delay
        call clrscr             ; clear the screen 
        push bx
        push dx
        call checkBorder
        mov ah,0x01
        int 0x16
        jz skip
        mov ah, 0
        int 0x16
        cmp al,0x77
        jz u
        cmp al,0x73
        jz d
        cmp al,0x61
        jz l
        cmp al,0x64
        jz r
        cmp al,0x1B
        jz ex
        skip:
            cmp al,0x71
            jnz l3
        
        u:
            sub dx,1
            mov [direction],2
            mov [snake_location]
            jmp l3
        d:
            add dx,1
            mov [direction],3
            jmp l3
        l:
            sub bx,1
            mov [direction],1
            jmp l3
        r:
            add bx,1
            mov [direction],0
            jmp l3
    ex:
    mov ax, 0x4c00
    int 0x21
length: dw 4
score: db 'Score: '
live: db 'Lives: '
slen: dw 7
gover: db 'Game Over!'
glen: dw 10
direction: db 0
snake_location:dw 0
```

Above is the code snippet for snake game in 8088 assembly language. It is not the complete code but includes the subroutine to check border for collision. Now I have no clue how to check for collision. I have tried to hard code but still it isn't efficient. Suggest me a way to check for collision of the snake. the snake has default length 4 with additional '0' character so it looks something like this "****0". The snake is printed from left to right. The collision will always be of '0' character but I don't know its position as snake is moving as keys are pressed so I can't figure out how to check for collision.

I am getting wrong results due to miscalculation of location of snakes head. I would appreciate any suggestions that would make code better. Thank you!

Comment: Whenever you print the snake's head just check what character is there. Surely you must know where you are printing?

Comment: One more thing, the snake moves only when I press a key. For instance, when I press arrow up key it moves one space up then stops. It should rather continue moving in that direction until another key is pressed. Can you kindly check the above code to resolve this issue. Thanks!

Comment: [The quintessential Snake Game. How to keep track of the snake?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66825708) has a couple different working versions of a snake game.  Your question is missing some pieces (like the `delay` and `printSnake` functions, so IDK where the snake grows now.)  It also has syntax errors like `mov word[snake_location],` missing the source operand for that line.

Comment: There are also no comments here about things like what a register is currently being used for.  Like `mov bx,20` is a mystery until later we see `mov ax, bx` / `push ax` with a comment that it's `x` position.  (Why not `push bx`?  And where's the `pop` or `add sp` to balance the stack?)