# How do you make something random disappear and then come back somewhere else randomly?

Tags: animation, assembly, random, game-development, x86-16

I'm making a snake game in assembly (very beginner level) and I'm stuck at the part where the apple is supposed to disappear and come back somewhere else randomly. I'm doing the randomness with the time.

I made the proc for the apple to appear randomly once:

```
proc apple
    mov ax, 40h
    mov es, ax
    mov ax, [es:6ch]
    and ax, 0000001111111110b
    mov di,ax
    mov ax, 0b800h
    mov es, ax
    
    mov al, '@'
    mov ah, 154
    mov [es:di], ax
    ret 
    endp apple
```

In the ds (dataseg) I wrote:

```
app dw 0
star dw (12*80+40)*2 ;the place of the snake
```

and honestly, from here I had a blackout.

For now my whole code is:

```
IDEAL
MODEL small
STACK 100h
DATASEG
; --------------------------
; Your variables here
; --------------------------
    saveal db ' '

app dw        ;place of the apple
star dw (12*80+40)*2  ;place of the *
st_am dw      ;nevermind this

CODESEG
proc black
body:
    mov [es:si], ax
    add si, 2
    cmp si, 25*80*2
    jnz body
  ret
endp black

proc up
    mov di, 80*2
    cmp si, di
    jb not_move_up
    
    mov ah, 0
    mov al, ' '
    mov [es:si], ax
    sub si, 80*2
    mov ah, 156
    mov al, '*'
    mov [es:si], ax
not_move_up:
  ret
endp up

proc down

    mov di, (24*80*2)-1
    cmp si, di
    jg not_move_down
    
    mov ah, 0
    mov al, ' '
    mov [es:si], ax
    add si, 80*2
    mov ah, 156
    mov al, '*'
    mov [es:si], ax
not_move_down:
  ret
endp down
proc left

    mov dx, 0
    mov bx, si
    mov ax, si
    mov si, 80*2
    div si
    mov si, bx
    cmp dx,0
    jz not_move_left
    
    mov ah, 0
    mov al, ' '
    mov [es:si], ax
    sub si, 2
    mov ah, 156
    mov al, '*'
    mov [es:si], ax
not_move_left:
  ret
endp left
proc right

    mov dx, 0
    mov bx, si
    mov ax, si
    mov si, 80*2
    div si
    mov si, bx
    cmp dx,158
    jz not_move_right

    mov ah, 0
    mov al, ' '
    mov [es:si], ax
    add si, 2
    mov ah, 156
    mov al, '*'
    mov [es:si], ax
not_move_right:
  ret
endp right

proc apple
    mov ax, 40h
    mov es, ax
    mov ax, [es:6ch]
    and ax, 0000001111111110b
    mov di,ax
    mov ax, 0b800h
    mov es, ax
    
    mov al, '@'
    mov ah, 154
    mov [es:di], ax
    ret 
    endp apple
start:
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax
; --------------------------
; Your code here
; --------------------------
    mov ax, 0b800h
    mov es, ax
    
    mov si,0
    mov al, ' '
    mov ah, 0
    call black
    mov si, (12*80+40)*2
    mov al, '*'
    mov ah, 156
    mov [es:si], ax
    call apple
    
    
    
yesOrno:
    mov ah, 1h
    int 21h
    
    mov [byte ptr saveal], al
    cmp [byte ptr saveal], 'w'
    jz w
    cmp [byte ptr saveal], 'a'
    jz a
    cmp [byte ptr saveal], 's'
    jz s
    cmp [byte ptr saveal], 'd'
    jz d
    cmp [byte ptr saveal], 'q'
    jmp exit
    
w:
    call up
    jmp yesOrno
s:
    call down
    jmp yesOrno 
a:
    call left
    jmp yesOrno
d:
    call right
    jmp yesOrno
    
exit:
    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h
END start
```

Comment: Some more comments could be useful. But besides that, you say that you are stuck, but how and why are you stuck? On [so] we expect concise questions, not partial code that we need to finish.

Answer (score 0):

Did you read [my answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77761089/how-to-make-a-pseudo-random-things-to-appear-after-one-another-on-screen) about the issue of randomly placing the apple?

With code like

> ```
> mov ax, [es:6ch]
> and ax, 0000001111111110b
> mov di, ax
> ```

you have made it even less random!
The procedure that I provided previously (and that is good enough for the sake of this humble exercise!), produces an X coordinate in AL and a Y coordinate in AH. Just combine the two values into an address in video memory following `((Y * 80) + X) * 2`:

```
xor  dx, dx
mov  dl, al    ; -> DX = X
mov  al, 80
mul  ah        ; -> AX = (Y * 80)
add  ax, dx    ; -> AX = (Y * 80) + X
add  ax, ax    ; -> AX = ((Y * 80) + X) * 2
```

> I'm stuck at the part where the apple is supposed to disappear and come back somewhere else randomly.

In order to make the apple disappear you need to remember where it was drawn, so **store its position** somewhere! Currently your *apple* proc does not do that.

```
ShowApple:
  call RandomAddress         ; -> AX (CX DX)
  mov  [word ptr AppleAddress], ax
  mov  di, ax
  mov  al, '@'
  mov  ah, 154
  mov  [es:di], ax
  ret

HideApple:
  mov  di, [word ptr AppleAddress]
  mov  al, ' '
  mov  ah, 0
  mov  [es:di], ax
  ret

; IN () OUT (ax) MOD (cx,dx)
RandomAddress:
  push ds
  xor  cx, cx
  mov  ds, cx
  mov  ax, [word ptr 046Ch]  ; DX:AX is [0,1573040]
  mov  dx, [word ptr 046Eh]
  mov  cl, 80
  div  cx                    ; -> AX is quotient [0,19663], DX is remainder [0,79]
  push dx                    ; (1)
  ; don't care if it got incremented in the mean time
  mov  ax, [word ptr 046Ch]  ; DX:AX is [0,1573040]
  mov  dx, [word ptr 046Eh]
  mov  cl, 25 
  div  cx                    ; -> AX is quotient [0,62921], DX is remainder [0,24]
  pop  ax                    ; (1)
  mov  ah, dl                ; -> AX has (X,Y) with AL is column and AH is row

  ; Convert to an address in video memory following `((Y * 80) + X) * 2`:

  xor  dx, dx
  mov  dl, al                ; -> DX = X
  mov  al, 80
  mul  ah                    ; -> AX = (Y * 80)
  add  ax, dx                ; -> AX = (Y * 80) + X
  add  ax, ax                ; -> AX = ((Y * 80) + X) * 2

  pop  ds
  ret
```

> See [The quintessential Snake Game. How to keep track of the snake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66825708/the-quintessential-snake-game-how-to-keep-track-of-the-snake) for more detailed info about creating a snake game, and especially look for the *NewFood* subroutines that use **another method of random number generation**.

Comment: Thank you so much but I there are some command I didn't learn yet.. but I did I succeeded at making it disappear and come back again.