# Why is it adding me a random pixel on the screen?

Tags: assembly, pixel, game-development, x86-16, dosbox

I'm making the snake game and I got to the part where there are (for now) 3 asterisks that make the snake. When I move from vertical to horizontal and from horizontal to vertical it adds another asterisk [image: this is how it looks before][image: this is how it looks after]
And for some reason just adds another `*` to the row of `*`s in the same place every time [image: after 3 times to the left][image: when I pressed left for the 4th time]

For now my code is:

```
IDEAL
MODEL small
STACK 100h
DATASEG
; --------------------------
; Your variables here
; --------------------------
saveal db, ' '  ;used in line 223-233

app dw 0       ;place of the apple
st_am dw 3
stars dw 0, 0, 0  ;places of the *

CODESEG
proc black
body:
    mov [es:si], ax
    add si, 2
    cmp si, 25*80*2
    jnz body
  ret
endp black

proc up
    mov di, 80*2
    cmp si, di
    jb not_move_up
    
    cmp si, [app]
    jnz move_up
    call apple
    
move_up:
    call delete
    
    mov di, [stars+2]
    mov [stars+4], di
    mov di, [stars]
    mov [stars+2], di
    sub di, 80*2
    mov ah, 156
    mov al, '*'
    mov [es:di], ax
    mov [stars], si
    
    sub si, 80*2
    mov ah, 156
    mov al, '*'
    mov [es:si], ax
    
not_move_up:
  ret
endp up

proc down

    mov di, (24*80*2)-1
    cmp si, di
    jg not_move_down
    
    cmp si, [offset app]
    jnz move_down
    call apple
    
move_down:
    call delete
    
    mov di, [stars+2]
    mov [stars+4], di
    mov di, [stars]
    mov [stars+2], di
    add di, 80*2
    mov ah, 156
    mov al, '*'
    mov [es:di], ax
    mov [stars], si
    
    add si, 80*2
    mov ah, 156
    mov al, '*'
    mov [es:si], ax
not_move_down:
  ret
endp down
proc left

    mov dx, 0
    mov bx, si
    mov ax, si
    mov si, 80*2
    div si
    mov si, bx
    cmp dx,0
    jz not_move_left
    
    cmp si, [offset app]
    jnz move_left
    call apple
    
move_left:
    call delete
    
    mov di, [stars+2]
    mov [stars+4], di
    mov di, [stars]
    mov [stars+2], di
    mov ah, 156
    mov al, '*'
    mov [es:di], ax
    mov [stars], si
    
    sub si, 2
    mov ah, 156
    mov al, '*'
    mov [es:si], ax
not_move_left:
  ret
endp left
proc right

    mov dx, 0
    mov bx, si
    mov ax, si
    mov si, 80*2
    div si
    mov si, bx
    cmp dx,158
    jz not_move_right
    
    cmp si, [app]
    jnz move_right
    call apple
    
move_right:
    call delete
    
    mov di, [stars+2]
    mov [stars+4], di
    mov di, [stars]
    mov [stars+2], di
    mov ah, 156
    mov al, '*'
    mov [es:di], ax
    mov [stars], si
    
    add si, 2
    mov ah, 156
    mov al, '*'
    mov [es:si], ax
not_move_right:
  ret
endp right

proc apple
    mov ax, 40h
    mov es, ax
    mov ax, [es:6ch]
    and ax, 0000001111111110b
    mov di,ax
    mov [offset app], di
    mov ax, 0b800h
    mov es, ax
    
    mov al, '@'
    mov ah, 154
    mov [es:di], ax
  ret 
endp apple
    
proc delete
    mov bx, offset stars
    mov di, [st_am]
    dec di
    shl di, 1
    mov di, [bx+di]
    mov ax, 0b800h
    mov es, ax
    
    mov al, ' '
    mov ah, 0
    
    mov [es:di], ax
  ret
endp delete
start:
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax
; --------------------------
; Your code here
; --------------------------
    mov ax, 0b800h
    mov es, ax
    
    mov si,0
    mov al, ' '
    mov ah, 0
    call black
    
    mov bx, offset stars
    
    mov si, ((12*80+40)*2)-2
    mov al, '*'
    mov ah, 156
    mov [es:si], ax
    mov [bx], si
    mov si, (12*80+40)*2
    mov al, '*'
    mov ah, 156
    mov [es:si], ax
    mov [bx+2], si
    mov si, ((12*80+40)*2)+2
    mov al, '*'
    mov ah, 156
    mov [es:si], ax
    mov [bx+4], si
    mov si, ((12*80+40)*2)-2    

    call apple
    
yesOrno:
    mov ah, 1h
    int 21h
    mov [byte ptr saveal], al
    
    cmp [byte ptr saveal], 'w'
    jz w
    cmp [byte ptr saveal], 'a'
    jz a
    cmp [byte ptr saveal], 's'
    jz s
    cmp [byte ptr saveal], 'd'
    jz d
    cmp [byte ptr saveal], 'q'
    jmp exit
    
w:
    call up
    jmp yesOrno
s:
    call down
    jmp yesOrno 
a:
    call left
    jmp yesOrno
d:
    call right
    jmp yesOrno
    
exit:
    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h
END start
```

I tried to think myself, but I couldn't think of something.
So sorry for asking a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Why there are extra characters.

> ```
> stars dw 0, 0, 0  ; addresses for the Head, Body, and Tail
> ```

You are not updating your *stars* array with the correct location of the snake's new head!
The `mov [stars], si` instruction needs to go **after** the update of the SI register (be it minus 160, plus 160, minus 2, or plus 2).

You are writing a redundant `*` in all of your movement procedures.
In *move_up* and *move_down* a redundant second `*` is placed where the new head will be drawn. And in *move_left* and *move_right* a redundant second `*` is placed where the old head is already drawn.

### Think about invalid moves.

You can not allow the snake to move to a location that already contains a part of the snake! Just check whether the screen already has a `*` and abandon the move accordingly. As an example the *move_up* code. The others are similar:

```
  ...
move_up:
  lea  di, [si - 160]       ; Intended address for the new head
  cmp  byte [es:di], '*'
  je   not_move_up          ; Illegal move
  call delete
  mov  ax, [stars+2]   \ These 3 lines really belong to
  mov  [stars+4], ax   |  the DELETE procedure (right before RET).
  mov  [stars+2], si   / Try to not repeat too much code.
  sub  si, 160
  mov  [stars], si          ; Update for the snake's new head
  mov  ax, 156 * 256 + '*'
  mov  [es:si], ax
not_move_up:
  ret
endp up
```

### Is this random enough?

> ```
> proc apple
>   mov ax, 40h
>   mov es, ax
>   mov ax, [es:6ch]
>   and ax, 0000001111111110b
>   mov di,ax
>   mov [offset app], di
> ```

For me, this way to choose a random location for the apple is broken. Do you think there is anything wrong with the suggestion I made in the answer to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77795829/how-do-you-make-something-random-disappear-and-then-come-back-somewhere-else-ran)?

Comment: I succeeded in the part where it doesn't leave me pixels on the screen (THANK YOU).
Honestly, I didn't really understand your answer for the randomness. the thing is, I'm really a beginner and I'm still learning about assembly. Maybe in the future I'll use it  !!
REALLY THANK YOU FOR HELPING ME !!!! <3